# Removing latitude and longitude labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating a map of Minnesota

```
map.test <- ggplot(kt_geom)+
  geom_polygon(aes(long, lat, group=group), fill="white")+
  geom_path(color="gray48", mapping=aes(long, lat, group=group), size=0.2)

map.test
```

and it displays the following map.

[image]

How can I remove the light gray background as well as the longitude and latitude axes? I know these won't appear if I use choropleth, but I need to use some functions within ggplot.

Comment: `+ ggthemes::theme_map()`

Comment: What does that even mean, @DreamWorks?

Comment: Thanks, @hrbrmstr, I've been using choropleth a lot but still new to ggplot, so this really helps.

Comment: + theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = 'transparent'))     will remove the grid lines as well.

Answer (score 20):

`theme(rect = element_blank())` will remove the gray background and (the appearance of) grid lines.

Adding `axis.ticks = element_blank()` will remove the tick marks, and `axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank()` will remove the lat/lon labels.

```
ggplot(kt_geom) +
  geom_polygon(aes(long, lat, group=group), fill="white") +
  geom_path(color="gray48", mapping=aes(long, lat, group=group), size=0.2) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        rect = element_blank())
```

In cases with a non-white background, you'll want to set `panel.grid.major = element_line(color = background_color)`, where, of course, `background_color` is the color of `panel.background`.

```
ggplot(kt_geom) +
  geom_polygon(aes(long, lat, group=group), fill="white") +
  geom_path(color="gray48", mapping=aes(long, lat, group=group), size=0.2) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "red"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "red"))
```

Comment: You're going to want to remove titles too (`axis.title.y=element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_blank()`)

Answer (score 10):

As hrbrmstr points out, `theme_map()` works:

```
library(ggthemes)
map.test <- ggplot(kt_geom)+
  geom_polygon(aes(long, lat, group=group), fill="white")+
  geom_path(color="gray48", mapping=aes(long, lat, group=group), size=0.2)+
  theme_map()

map.test
```

[image]